# Python - Text overriding when printed in single line

Tags: python, sockets

Option 1:

Server Part:

```
def send_waiting_messages(wlist,sent):
for message in messages_to_send:
    (client_socket,data) = message
    client_socket.send(str(users_sockets.get(sent)) + ": ")
    client_socket.send(str(data))
    messages_to_send.remove(message)
```

Client Part:

```
data = current_socket.recv(4096)
        print data
```

When I'm using this server's code, the text that is recieved looks like that:

```
Username: 
text
```

Option 2:

Server Part:

```
def send_waiting_messages(wlist,sent):
for message in messages_to_send:
    (client_socket,data) = message
    client_socket.send(str(users_sockets.get(sent)) + ": " + str(data))
    messages_to_send.remove(message)
```

When I'm using this code, the text that is recieved looks weird.
For example, if the username is "Amit" and the text is "Hi", the text looks like that:

```
Hiit:
```

You can see that basically the text overrides the username. The server sents something like that: **Username**Text-overlapped characters.

Username: aaaa

Text: bb

Result: bbaa:

Comment: It seems like for some reason print ends with a carriage return (`\r`) instead of a newline..

Comment: Ok, so what do I need to do to fix it?